# How can I create table named as current date in python MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I am creating a table in python MySQL and want to use the current date as table name. My code giving an error. here is my code:

```
def create():
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='localhost', database='college', password='$@ffron@09')
cur = conn.cursor()
current_date = date.today()
query = 'create table %s(Name char(40) not null,Academic_year VARCHAR(5) not null ,Serial_number varchar(20) primary key ,Father_name char(20) not null, Mother_name char(20) not null,Email_id VARCHAR(25) not null unique,Contact_number int not null,Semester VARCHAR(5) not null)'
data=(current_date,)
cur.execute(query,data)

create()
```

This code throwing an error: MySQL.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2021-04-13'(Name char(40) not null,Academic_year VARCHAR(5) not null ,Serial_nu' at line 1

How can I achieve this and rectify this error?

Comment: Creating one table per day (which is what your answer seems to imply) suggests that you might have a design problem.  Why do you want to create new tables per some interval of time?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen actually I want  current date as my table name.

Comment: We understand that is what you want. What we are trying to suggest is that what you want is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: I want to store everyday records for which I have to maintain tables for the everyday record. for fetching the data of a particular day I have to give the unique name of the table that's why I thought to give the name as date.if there is any better way to do so, please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has some limitations:
[schema object names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

As you can see it mentions 'quoted' and 'unquoted' names. You can have less restrictions on names if you have it 'quoted'. Use the `` signs around your `table_name` for that. Not sure if you can use it right these way in python but try:

```
query = 'create table `%s`(Name char(40) not null,Academic_year VARCHAR(5) not null ,Serial_number varchar(20) primary key ,Father_name char(20) not null, Mother_name char(20) not null,Email_id VARCHAR(25) not null unique,Contact_number int not null,Semester VARCHAR(5) not null)'
```